# Impala Query Error - AnalysisException: operands of type INT and STRING are not comparable

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera, impala, hue

I am trying to execute a query in Impala and getting the following error (AnalysisException: operands of type INT and STRING are not comparable: B.COMMENT_TYPE_CD = '100' ) can someone help me fix this: 
Query:

```
SELECT 
ORDER_ID,
L1.LONG_TEXT
FROM 
DB.ORDER_COMMENT A,
DB.SHORT_TEXT L1
WHERE  ACTION_SEQUENCE = (
    SELECT MAX(ACTION_SEQUENCE) 
    FROM DB.ORDER_COMMENT B
    WHERE B.COMMENT_TYPE_CD='100' 
    AND A.ORDER_ID=B.ORDER_ID) 
AND COMMENT_TYPE_CD='100'
AND A.LONG_TEXT_ID=L1.LONG_TEXT_ID 
AND L1.ACTIVE_IND=1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the table structure makes this a guess, but... Is it possible that COMMENT_TYPE_CD field is an INT in DB.ORDER_COMMENT table? If so, you should remove the quotes in `'100'` and let just `100`

Comment: Tried that now I get this error - [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 42000, SQL state: Syntax error or access violation, Query: AEValueSubQuery is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

1st Approach:

```
COMMENT_TYPE_CD=100
```

2nd Approach:

```
cast(COMMENT_TYPE_CD as string)='100'
```